# The Errors messages in edit actions, doesn't appear

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, action

I have my validation rules in model, and everything is fine. It validates like I want to, but in the Edit actions, although it not validates, don't show me de red error marks under textbox.

Any tip?

Thanks.

The Model Code(Model name is Safpercent):

```
var $validate = array(
        'sequencia' => array(
            'must_be_numeric' => array(
                'rule' => 'Numeric',
                'message' => 'Number Field: insert only numbers.' 
            )
        ),
    );
```

View Text Box:

```
echo $form->input('Safpercent.sequence', array('id' => 'sequence', 'options' => $criteria, 'label' => false, 'div' => false, 'style' => 'width: 300px'));
```

Controller Code:

```
function edit($id = null) {
                $criteria = $this->Safpercent->Safrequirement->find('list', array('fields' => array('Safrequirement.sequencia', 'Safrequirement.descricao'), 'conditions' => array('Safrequirement.tipo' => 'ILC')));
                $this->set('criteria', $criteria);
                if (!$id && empty($this->data)) {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(RecordNotValid, 'flash_failure');
                    $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'safpercents', 'action'=>'index'));
        }
        if (!empty($this->data)) {
                    $sequencia = $this->data['Safpercent']['sequencia'];
                    if($this->data['Safpercent']['tipo'] == ''){$tipo = 'ILC';}else{$tipo = $this->data['Safpercent']['tipo'];} 
                    $encontro = $this->Safpercent->Safrequirement->find('all', array('conditions' => array('sequencia' => $sequencia, 'tipo' => $tipo)));
            if($encontro <> array()){
                        if ($this->Safpercent->save($this->data)) {
                            $this->Session->setFlash(RecordSaved, 'flash_success');
                            $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'safpercents', 'action'=>'index'));
                        }else{
                            $this->Session->setFlash(RecordNotSaved, 'flash_failure');
                        }
                    }else{
                        $this->Session->setFlash('A Sequência que tentou Inserir não existe. Verifique a tabela de novo, por favor.');
                    }   
                }
        if (empty($this->data)) {
                    $this->data = $this->Safpercent->read(null, $id);
                    $this->set('id', $id);
        }
                $this->set('cod_percent',$this->Safpercent->read(null, $id));
    }
```

(Portuguese Variables and Text in some cases)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see now. In your controller, you are using the `sequencia` field that you are validating, but not doing any validation at this stage. It passes a non-number to the `find` query, which then returns an error or something, and the `save` never gets called?

Before you do this:

```
$sequencia = $this->data['Safpercent']['sequencia'];
```

You should check that the data validates, by calling this:

```
$this->ModelName->set($this->data);
if ($this->ModelName->validates()) {
    ... //do your business here
```

So basically, change:

```
if (!empty($this->data)) {
```

to:

```
$this->Safpercent->set($this->data);
if (!empty($this->data) && $this->Safpercent->validates()) {
```

Comment: It isn't that. I remove that part, but still the same problem. (My add views has de div='false' and it works just fine.)

Comment: In that case, can you edit the question to include the code from the controller?

Comment: @Jake, I used  debug($this->Safpercent->validationErrors) in other controller. When I use it in de correct one, does not show me any errors. The Debug results are: Array()

Comment: @Rafael Santos No worries. In that case, can we see the code from the controller please?

Comment: @Rafael Santos Does the error message ("Number Field: insert only numbers.") show just without the styling? Or does it just show the normal form field? Does it preserve the data entered?

Comment: in Add action it shows normaly the error. Red box bellow the textbox, it preserves the data. But in edit action, the red box dosent appear although it preserves the data.

Comment: That doesn't show the error message either :S
(but I know that the validation is working, because when the data is right it saves on the Database.)

Comment: Same thing, the damn redbox doesn't appear.

Comment: @Rafael My mistake, you've gotta set the data first. Add in a `$this->Safpercent->set($this->data);` before you check it validates. Sorry.

Comment: I put that piece you gave me, before it checks, and now don't validate xD  previously it validate. I'm starting to think if it's a deep thing, like configurations or similar

Answer (score 2):

Try

> debug($this->Safpercent->validationErrors)

and see if it shows any errors.

Comment: I tried that and it displays two "yellow-cake" errors, going to put the erros on the first post.

Comment: Add `var $uses = array('Safpercent');` at the top of the controller before the functions.

Comment: that errors, was because I put debug($this->Safpercent->validationErrors) on other controller. I'm so dumb, going to try in the correct controller.

Comment: @Rafael pls provide the code where u save the record and following.